# What is the track listing for "selector spread WIXOSS music Particle.2"?

Tags: music, wixoss

The second half of the soundtrack for the WIXOSS anime came on the album ["selector spread WIXOSS music Particle.2"](http://vgmdb.net/album/49081). This album was released with [the second spread WIXOSS box set](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%80%8Cselector-spread-WIXOSS%E3%80%8DBOX2-%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%83%83%E3%82%AD%E4%BB%98-Blu-ray/dp/B00OH1K9DG/) back in April. For whatever reason, though, the track listing for this album does not appear to be available anywhere on the internet.

What is the list of tracks on this album?

Comment: There is indeed not yet any listing. Even Japanese Wikipedia doesn't have it: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selector%E3%81%AE%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3#selector_spread_WIXOSS_music_particle.2

Answer (score 1):

Some nice person added the track listing to VGMdb a little while back (I assume it's correct, though there are no scans of the listing included); here is a romanized / translated<sup>†</sup> version of it:

1. Battle ~ I can make your wish come true
2. *doushite naite iru no?* / "Why are you crying?"
3. *fushigi* / "Strange"
4. *Chiyori* / "Chiyori"
5. *chiyoringaa, chiyorunbaa, chorisoo*
6. *gikochinai*  / "Awkward"
7. *yukkuri to* / "Slowly"
8. *Urisu to Iona* / "Ulith and Iona"
9. *uso to yokubou, kowarete guchagucha* / "Lies and desires come tumbling down"
10. *Iona to Akira* / "Iona and Akira"
11. *iradachi to kyoufu* / "Anger and fear"
12. *kenshin to izon ~ Devotion* / "Sacrifice and dependence ~ Devotion"
13. Conflict
14. *atarashii katachi* / "A new form"
15. *nichijou ~ Futase* / "Life ~ Futase"
16. *mayoimichi* / "Gone astray"
17. *Fumio* / "Fumio"
18. *Battle ~ mou, genkai nan da* / "Battle ~ I can't go any further"
19. *Mayu to shiroi heya* / "Mayu and the white room"
20. *hibiware ~ Brasted piano* / "A crack ~ Brasted piano"
21. *Ulith* / "Ulith"
22. *omoikomi?* / "A preconception?"
23. *utsuro na sonzai* / "A hollow existence"
24. *minna de yarinaosou?* / "Why don't we all start over?"
25. Battle ~ Consternation
26. *taiji to itami* / "Confrontation and pain"
27. *kizu* / "Injury"
28. *dakedo* / "But"
29. *Yuki* / "Yuki"
30. Profane Wish ~ Brasted piano
31. *moshikashitara* / "What if"
32. *sorezore no yasashisa* / "Kindness, each in their own way"
33. *tobira* / "The gate"
34. infinite Girl

---

<sup>†</sup> Except for track 5, because what do you even do with that? Also, because I'm lazy, I didn't pull the translations for things like tracks 22 and 23 from the simulcast subtitles, so they'll probably be sort of discrepant.